# Animations: moving a UIView up and off the screen by its height - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to move a UIView up and off the screen by its height in ios.  Below is my code for doing this.  What I am finding is that the UIView does indeed move up and off the screen but instead of moving slowly as intended it continues to move off instantaneously without animation.  Please can someone advise?

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 300, animations: {
                    let heightOfViewContainingProgrBar = self.viewContainingProgressBar.frame.height
                    self.viewContainingProgressBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -heightOfViewContainingProgrBar).isActive = true
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a call to layoutIfNeeded (for the view or one of it's superviews) inside the animation block.

Comment: I tried self.viewContainingProgressBar.layoutIfNeeded() inside the animation block as you suggested but it still does not work.  Not sure if this was what you meant ... perhaps you could code it out for me?

Comment: Try modifying the constant on an existing constraint (which you would need to link to an outlet) rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

inside animation block